# Given two points, how to find a circle through them that's also tangent to the $x$-axis?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles

A seemingly simple geometry problem that is surprisingly difficult. I want to find the radius of a circle that is tangent to the $x$-axis, but also must contain two given points.  I understand there are many situations that have no solution, but for those that **do** have a solution, how can I find it?

For the image below, the circle origin is at $(d_s, R_0)$, the first point is at $(0,h_s)$, and the second point is at $(d,h_r)$.  For valid solutions, $h_s$, $h_r$, and $d$ must all be less than $R_0$.  The known quantities are $h_s$, $h_r$, and $d$, and the unknowns are $R_0$ and $d_s$.

[image]

Comment: Would it help if you had a geometric construction to make the circle to start with?

Comment: There are too many constraints, do you want to determine centre of circle from those constraints? , for e.g, $d_s=\sqrt{2h_s R_0-h_s^2}$ , where positive root is taken as according to diagram.

Comment: Are you looking for an analytical solution, or a construction?  And are you restricting the scenarios to the case depicted above, where the point of tangency is between the points on the $x$-axis directly "below" the two points?

Comment: I do understand the problem can be over-constrained.  The solutions I am interested in does need to follow the diagram.  A possibly more detailed description is that a ball leaves the first point (0,hs), travels along a circular arc tangent to the ground, and arrives at (d,hs).  How big is the circle (R0)?

Comment: A Euclidean geometry construction: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/GeoGebra/PPL.shtml

Comment: Also, why do you require $h_r, h_s, d < R_0$?  Is there a reason for that?  There are many cases where we have circles passing through the two points, and all three of those are greater than $R_0$.  (For instance, if the two points are at $(0, 1)$ and $(1, 1)$, and then $R_0 = 5/8$.)  Why do you wish to eliminate those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An analytical solution: The midpoint of the two points is $(\frac{d}{2}, \frac{h_s+h_r}{2})$, so the equation of their perpendicular bisector is

$$
y-\frac{h_s+h_r}{2} = \frac{d}{h_s-h_r} \left(x-\frac{d}{2}\right)
$$

The center must lie on that bisector.  It must also be equidistant from the $x$-axis and the given point on the $y$-axis:

$$
y^2 = x^2 + (y-h_s)^2
$$

which yields

$$
y = \frac{x^2+h_s^2}{2h_s}
$$

Substitution into the bisector equation gives us

$$
\frac{x^2+h_s^2}{2h_s}-\frac{h_s+h_r}{2}
    = \frac{d}{h_s-h_r} \left(x-\frac{d}{2}\right)
$$

Multiply both sides by $2h_s(h_s-h_r)$ to get

$$
(x^2+h_s^2)(h_s-h_r)-h_s(h_s^2-h_r^2) = dh_s(2x-d)
$$

or

$$
(h_s-h_r)x^2 - 2dh_sx + d^2h_s-h_rh_s(h_s-h_r) = 0
$$

which yields

$$
d_s = x = \frac{dh_s \pm \sqrt{d^2h_s^2-(h_s-h_r)[d^2h_s-h_rh_s(h_s-h_r)]}}{h_s-h_r}
$$

When there are two solutions, one is "between" the two points, and the other is "on the outside", on the side of the "lower" point.  And then the radius $R_0$ is given by

$$
R_0 = y = \frac{d}{h_s-h_r} \left(x-\frac{d}{2}\right) + \frac{h_s+h_r}{2}
$$

ETA: It seems much less messy in any individual scenario with specific values for $d, h_s, h_r$.

Comment: Fantastic!  And I did make a mistake earlier. d needs to be less than 2*R0.  Thanks!

Comment: Is my answer the same as yours, only that I've named the points differently and expanded the brackets?

Answer (score 1):

Let the points be $(a,b)$ and $(0,c)$. The construction I used was constructing the perpendicular bisector of the two points, and a parabola with directrix as a line $y=-c$ and focus at $(0,c)$. The $x$-axis is parallel to the directrix and the $y$-axis passes through the parabola's focus. Note that I am trying to make a circle passing through the two points tangent to the $-c$ line, not the $x$-axis as in the original question (it makes calculations easier).

The perpendicular bisector contains all points equidistant from the two points, and the circle's center must lie on it. The parabola contains all points equidistant from the $(0,c)$ point and the $-c$ line. The circle's center must also lie on this parabola. Thus the center must be on the intersection of the parabola and the perpendicular bisector.

I got equations for the bisector and the parabola, and then gave them to Wolfram Alpha to solve them. Here's what I got: assuming $b,c\neq 0$ and $b-c\neq 0$ (reasonable assumptions), the *two* points which can be centers of eligible circles are
$$
x = \frac{\mp \sqrt{2cd}-2ac}{b-c} \\
y = \frac{\pm 2a\sqrt{2cd}+d}{2(c-b)^2} \\
\text{where } d = a^2b + a^2c + b^3 - 3b^2c + 3bc^2 - c^3
$$
with radii equal to their respective $y$ parts, plus $c$ because the original line is at $-c$. The distance from the center of the circle to the $y$-axis is the $x$ part of the center. Whew.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

A circle that has center $(\alpha, \beta)$ and is tangent to the $x$ axis has equation:
$$
(x-\alpha)^2+(y-\beta)^2=\beta^2
$$

Substiute the coordinate of the two points and find $(\alpha,\beta)$.